# Spark join dataframes & datasets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `DataFrame` called **Link** with a dynamic amount of fields/columns in a `Row`.
Some fields however had the structure **[ClassName]Id** that contain an id

**[ClassName]Id**'s are always of type `String`

I have a couple of `Datasets` each of a different type **[ClassName]**
Each `Dataset` has at least fields `id` (`String`) and `typeName` (`String`), which is always filled with the String value of the `[ClassName]`

e.g. If I would have 3 `DataSets` of type **A**, **B** and **C**

**Link:**

`+----+-----+-----+-----+
 | id | AId | BId | CId |
 +----+-----+-----+-----+
 | XX | A01 | B02 | C04 |
 | XY | null| B05 | C07 |`

**A:**

`+-----+----------+-----+-----+
 | id  | typeName | ... | ... |
 +-----+----------+-----+-----+
 | A01 | A        | ... | ... |`

**B:**

`+-----+----------+-----+-----+
 | id  | typeName | ... | ... |
 +-----+----------+-----+-----+
 | B02 | B        | ... | ... |`

The preferred end result would be the **Link** `Dataframe` where each Id is either replace or appended by a field called `[ClassName]` With the original object encapsulated.

**Result:**

`+----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 | id | A              | B              | C              |
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 | XX | A(A01, A, ...) | B(B02, B, ...) | C(C04, C, ...) |
 | XY | null           | B(B05, B, ...) | C(C07, C, ...) |`

**Things I've tried**

- **Recursive Call on joinWith**. 
  The first call succeeds returning a tuple/`Row` where the first element is the original `Row` and the second the matched `[ClassName]`
  However the second iteration starts nesting these results.
  Trying to 'unnest' these results using map either results in Encoder hell (since the resulting `Row` is not a fixed type) or the Encoding is so complex that it results in a catalyst [error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18492)
- **join as RDD** Can't work this one out yet.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Would you care reviewing it so we can try to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how I could do what I want. 
I made some changes for it to work for me, but it's a 
For reference purpose I will show my steps, maybe it can be useful for someone in the future?

1. First I declare a datatype that shares all properties of **A, B, C**, etc. that I'm Interested in and make the classes extend from this super type

```scala
case class Base(id: String, typeName: String)
case class A(override val id: String, override val typeName: String) extends Base(id, typeName)
```

2. Next I load the link `Dataframe`

```scala
val linkDataFrame = spark.read.parquet("[path]")
```

3. I want to convert this `DataFrame` in something joinable, this means creating a placeholder for the joined sources and a way to convert all the single `Id` fields (AId, BId, etc) into a `Map` of source -> id's. Spark has a [sql `map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map(scala.collection.Seq)) method that is useful. Also we need to convert the `Base` class to a `StructType` for use in the encoder. Tried multiple ways, but couldn't circumvent specific declaration (otherwise casting errors)

```scala
val linkDataFrame = spark.read.parquet("[path]")

case class LinkReformatted(ids: Map[String, Long], sources: Map[String, Base])

// Maps each column ending with Id into a Map of (columnname1 (-Id), value1, columnname2 (-Id), value2)
val mapper = linkDataFrame.columns.toList
  .filter(
    _.matches("(?i).*Id$")
  )
  .flatMap(
    c => List(lit(c.replaceAll("(?i)Id$", "")), col(c))
)

val baseStructType = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Base].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

4. All these parts made it possible to create a new `DataFrame` with the Id's all in one field called **ids** and a placeholder for the **sources** in an empty `Map[String, Base]`

```scala
val linkDatasetReformatted = linkDataFrame.select(
    map(mapper: _*).alias("ids")
  )
  .withColumn("sources", lit(null).cast(MapType(StringType, baseStructType)))
  .as[LinkReformatted]
```

5. The next step was to join all source `Datasets` (A,B, etc) to this reformatted **Link** dataset. A lot of stuff happens in this tailrecursive method

```scala
@tailrec
def recursiveJoinBases(sourceDataset: Dataset[LinkReformatted], datasets: List[Dataset[Base]]): Dataset[LinkReformatted] = datasets match {
  case Nil => sourceDataset // Nothing left to join, return it
  case baseDataset :: remainingDatasets => {

    val typeName = baseDataset.head.typeName // extract the type from base (each field hase same value)
    val masterName = "source" // something to name the source

    val joinedDataset = sourceDataset.as(masterName) // joining source
      .joinWith(
      baseDataset.as(typeName), // with a base A,B, etc
      col(s"$typeName.id") === col(s"$masterName.ids.$typeName"), // join on source.ids.[typeName]
      "left_outer"
    )
      .map {
        case (source, base) => {
          val newSources = if (source.sources == null) Map(typeName -> base) else source.sources + (typeName -> base) // append or create map of sources          
          source.copy(sources = newSources)
        }
      }
      .as[LinkReformatted]
    recursiveJoinBases(joinedDataset, remainingDatasets)
  }
}
```

6. You now end up with a `Dataset` of `LinkReformatted` records where for each corresponding `typeName -> id` in the **ids** field is a corresponding  `typeName -> Base` in the **sources** field.
   For me that was enough. I could extract everything I needed using some map function over this final Dataset

I hope this somewhat helps. I understand it's not the exact solution I was asking about, nor is it all very straightforward.